# python flask mongodb insert data

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, flask, pymongo

how do i insert data to a specific user in python flask mongodb

```py
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e208aa1f86973bbd7db6e8a"),
    "worker_name" : "user1",
    "location" : "location1",
    "detection" : [ ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e208aa1f86973bbd7db6e8b"),
    "worker_name" : "user2",
    "location" : "location2",
    "detection" : [ ]
}
```

above are my users, I want to insert some data in `user1 detection` list, below are my code i had tried

```py
def face_detection():
    face_module = mongo.db.face_modules
    user = mongo.db.users
    stream_link = request.form['stream_link']
    location = request.form['location']
    camera = request.form['camera']
    result = {
            "location": location,
            "stream_url": stream_link,
            "worker_name": "user1",
            "date": "1/1/2020",
            "hour": "9",
            "minute": "10",
            "second": "25"
        }
    if user.find({"worker_name": result['worker_name']}).count() > 0:
        update_user = user.detection.insert(result)
        output = "user updated"
        return jsonify({'result': output})
```

Comment: so what error are you getting? did you mean to use ``insert_one`` instead of ``insert``?

Comment: @GonzaloHernandez i dont know I'm new to flask python , i want that `result` dictionary should insert to a `user1` detection list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the document already exists you need to update it rather than insert, Also as you wanted to insert something into an array it should be through `$push`, Plus instead of making two DB calls you can use `find_one_and_update` which will return updated document with this option :: `return_document = ReturnDocument.AFTER` or will return `none` incase of no matching document found. Based on that you can return the response. In general you would use `insert` or `insert_one` for inserting a new document to colleciton. I'm a bit new to `pymongo`, Please add the code to check error scenario from DB, Plus test this code & you're feel free to update this answer with any findings..

Try this :

```
def face_detection():
face_module = mongo.db.face_modules
user = mongo.db.users
stream_link = request.form['stream_link']
location = request.form['location']
camera = request.form['camera']
result = {
        "location": location,
        "stream_url": stream_link,
        "worker_name": "user1",
        "date": "1/1/2020",
        "hour": "9",
        "minute": "10",
        "second": "25"
    }
resp = user.find_one_and_update(
    {"worker_name": result['worker_name']},
    { '$push': {'detection' : result} },
    return_document = ReturnDocument.AFTER)


if resp :
    return jsonify({'result': resp})
else :
    return jsonify({'result': 'No document found'})
```

Comment: its working but its not generating id's of result , there are 2 collections one of user which have list of `detection` and  other  collection name `detection` i want the same detection with its id should add to the user

Comment: @chiragprajapati : MongoDB is NoSQL there is no relation between two collections, if you need that relation either you need to add `detection` documents as sub-documents to relative document of `user` or you need to pass `ids` of relative `detection` documents when inserting/updating documents in `user`. You can read two collections with one query, but you cannot write to two collections, there are no relations..

Comment: yes, i want `detection` document as sub-documents to relative document of `user` , how can i do that?

Comment: @chiragprajapati : what do you mean by that ? When inserting data in `detection` collection, you need to insert respective `ids` for detection documents in `user` collection, You've to do that through code/manually - MongoDB can't do it.

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: @chiragprajapati : It all depends on how your application works, With all information you've maybe you can raise a new question, myself or someone can help you with best possible ways.